# prolog generate list of numbers from a list[x,y]

Tags: prolog

Hello I want to generate a list as following. Given a list like [x,y] I want to generate a list that is x,x,...,x : y times eg `[2,3]=[2,2,2]` but I cannot figure out how.

This is my implementation so far:

```
generate([T,1],[T]).
generate([X,S],[X|T]):-S1 is S-1,generate([X,S1],[T]).
```

but for some reason it fails. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your second clause. When you have `[X|T]`, it means that T is a list. In the body you write `generate([X,S1],[T])`: by writing `[T]` you're now saying the second argument to generate is a list of which the only element is this list T. What you want to say is that it is simply this list T:

```
generate([T,1], [T]).
generate([X,S], [X|T]) :- S1 is S-1, generate([X,S1], T).
```

Comment: `generate([e,3], Xs)` does not terminate.

Comment: Try it with, e.g. `generate([e,3], Xs), Xs = []` which should fail

Answer (score 2):

```
generate([E,R], Es) :-
   length(Es, R),
   maplist(=(E), Es).
```

You said that your version fails. But in fact it does not:

```
?- generate([a,0], Xs).
   false.
?- generate([a,1], Xs).
   Xs = [a]
;  false.
?- generate([a,2], Xs).
   Xs = [a|a]
;  false.
?- generate([a,3], Xs).
   false.
```

It doesn't work for 0, seems to work for length 1, then, produces an incorrect solution `Xs = [a|a]` for length 2, and finally fails from length 3 on. `[a|a]` is a good hint that at someplace in your definition, lists and their elements are confused. To better distinguish them, use a variable in plural for a list, like `Es` which is the plural of `E`.